# Get file name from URL in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following JS, and I'm looking to produce a link whose text is the file's name, shown below as "WHAT AM I."

```
function ( val) {
    var table = $('#qpidvulh_tracking').DataTable();
    url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/dcturano/tracking/"+val+"_"+table.file('files', val).fileName;
    console.log("URL:"+url);
    link = "<a href='"+url+"' target='_blank'>"WHAT AM I"</a>"
    return link;
```

Comment: link = "<a href='"+url+"' target='_blank'>'+table.file('files', val).fileName+'</a>"?

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the filename accessible via the `table.file('files', val).fileName` variable, just use that.

A more generic way which simply extracts the filename from the full URL:

```
function ( val) {
    var table = $('#qpidvulh_tracking').DataTable();
    url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/dcturano/tracking/"+val+"_"+table.file('files', val).fileName;
    console.log("URL:"+url);
    link = "<a href='"+url+"' target='_blank'>"+url.split('/').slice(-1)[0]+"</a>"
    return link;
}
```

Simply split the url string on the `/` character and take the last element from the resulting array.